# Submit form after certain time interval through laravel 5.3

Tags: jquery, laravel, security, laravel-5

I am developing a time based mock test web application. I need to securely submit form after lets say 5 mins. if i do it with jquery wouldn't it be less secure?? or doing it with php/ laravel functions will make it more secure?? and if there is a way of doing it with php/laravel please guide how to do it. Thanku

Comment: you can use ajax, call a controller laravel and submit the form normaly

Comment: well i think that ajax and javascript code can be manipulated easily if i am not wrong???

Comment: laravel have a csrf token that give secure call ajax or form requrest, you can try to change the values of call ajax and see that will not work because the token will be not accept

Comment: ok. Share with me how to correctly submit form after 5 seconds. assume i know ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [laravel queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#delayed-dispatching).

After submitting the form you can call the function and after 5 minutes (in the example 10) you can submit the form to your database or email.

Comment: i have read it. it will only delay the process and nothing more. i want that if a person takes a test than after 60 seconds the form should submit